# Environment suggestion appreciated

Tags: environments

I'm trying to achieve construction like this:

[image]

however I've been pretty unsuccesfull achieving that so far.
I think I tried all the wrong environments for that - added that as math function lead problem with indentation  and the two double(tripple) lines on the right side are also problematic. I tried the array, couldn't force lyx to have the braces across all the lines. Last time I used a table, but in that case the braces don't stretch across all the lines...

As flexible as Latex is, I think I must have missed some easier way how to achieve this.

BTW: I don't care about the dots on the right side as long as the two parts are somehow separated - ideally like a paragraph.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks for any feedback

Comment: is TikZ allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray, multirow}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\newcommand\mycbox[1]{\colorbox{white}{\color{red}\bfseries#1}}

\begin{document}

\sffamily \[%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\colorbox{blue}{\color{yellow}\begin{blockarray}{l <{\enspace }\}@{\qquad} >{\color{white}\setstretch{1.33}}l}
\mycbox{Carburizing} & \multirow{4}{7cm}[3ex]{%
\begin{itemize}[wide = 0pt ]
    \item Forming harder and stronger surface \MVRightArrow{} introducing compressive residual stress
    \item The strengthening effect depends on the diameter of the part and the depth of the surface hardening. 
\end{itemize}}\\
\mycbox{Nitriding} \\
\mycbox{Flame hardening} \\
\mycbox{Induction hardening} \\
  \end{blockarray} }
            \]%
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a black & white version, remove xcolor loading and use this code:

```
\[%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{blockarray}{ >{\enspace $\sffamily\bfseries}l <{\enspace $}\}@{\qquad} >{\setstretch{1.33}}l <{\enspace}}
Carburizing & \multirow{4}{6.3cm}[3ex]{%
\begin{itemize}[wide = 0pt ]
    \item Forming harder and stronger surface \MVRightArrow{} introducing compressive residual stress
    \item The strengthening effect depends on the diameter of the part and the depth of the surface hardening.
\end{itemize}}\\
Nitriding \\
Flame hardening \\
Induction hardening \\
  \end{blockarray}
            \]%
```

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, you took it to another level :D I was struggling with the structure itself, the colouring is not an issue (nor desired, sorry for not mentioning that).
How about plain B&W mode?

Comment: I basically need to copy part of that presentation into a report I'm writing....

Comment: Do you want a frame replacing the blue box?

Comment: Dont need the blue box at all, just add the text ie. the 4 lines on the left, 2 "paragraphs" on the right separated by the braces (height of the taller side

Comment: @Birimaratoa: Please see my updated answer. Is that OK?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a `tcolorbox` based solution. The first environment follows your picture with some additions like rounded corners for the red boxes.

The following two add titles, adjust the width of the red boxes, and finally add a fancy shadow (just for fun):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{enumitem,pifont}

\newtcolorbox{myenvironment}[1][]{%
  enhanced,sidebyside,lefthand width=3.7cm,%
  sharp corners,left=2mm,right=2mm,boxrule=0.4pt,
  colframe=blue!50!black,
  interior style={left color=blue!75!black,right color=blue},
  lower separated=false,
  fontlower=\sffamily\large,
  overlay={\draw[yellow,solid,very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt}]
    ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=-3mm]segmentation.north) -- ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=3mm]segmentation.south);},
  raster columns=1,
  raster force size=false,
  raster every box/.style={enhanced,fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,size=small,
    colupper=red,colback=white,colframe=red!50!white,center upper},
  before upper=\begin{tcbraster},
  after upper=\end{tcbraster},
  before lower={\flushleft\color{white}\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt]},
  after lower={\end{itemize}},
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,center title,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvironment}
  \tcbox{Carburizing}
  \tcbox{Nitriding}
  \tcbox{Flame hardening}
  \tcbox{Induction hardening}
\tcblower
  \item Forming harder and stronger surface \ding{212} introducing compressive
    residual stress.
  \item The strengthening effect depends on the diameter of the part and the
    depth of the surface hardening.
\end{myenvironment}

\begin{myenvironment}[raster force size,title=My environment]
  \tcbox{Carburizing}
  \tcbox{Nitriding}
  \tcbox{Flame hardening}
  \tcbox{Induction hardening}
\tcblower
  \item Forming harder and stronger surface \ding{212} introducing compressive
    residual stress.
  \item The strengthening effect depends on the diameter of the part and the
    depth of the surface hardening.
\end{myenvironment}

\begin{myenvironment}[raster force size,title=My environment,
  rounded corners,drop fuzzy shadow]
  \tcbox{Carburizing}
  \tcbox{Nitriding}
  \tcbox{Flame hardening}
  \tcbox{Induction hardening}
\tcblower
  \item Forming harder and stronger surface \ding{212} introducing compressive
    residual stress.
  \item The strengthening effect depends on the diameter of the part and the
    depth of the surface hardening.
\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The left hand width is set manually, e.g. for a shorter one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{enumitem,pifont}

\newtcolorbox{myenvironment}[1][]{%
  enhanced,sidebyside,lefthand width=3.7cm,%
  sharp corners,left=2mm,right=2mm,boxrule=0.4pt,
  colframe=blue!50!black,
  interior style={left color=blue!75!black,right color=blue},
  lower separated=false,
  fontlower=\sffamily\large,
  overlay={\draw[yellow,solid,very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt}]
    ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=-3mm]segmentation.north) -- ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=3mm]segmentation.south);},
  raster columns=1,
  raster force size=false,
  raster every box/.style={enhanced,fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,size=small,
    colupper=red,colback=white,colframe=red!50!white,center upper},
  before upper=\begin{tcbraster},
  after upper=\end{tcbraster},
  before lower={\flushleft\color{white}\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt]},
  after lower={\end{itemize}},
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,center title,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvironment}[lefthand width=3cm]
  \tcbox{Carburizing}
  \tcbox{Nitriding}
  \tcbox{Flame hard.}
  \tcbox{Induction hard.}
\tcblower
  \item Forming harder and stronger surface \ding{212} introducing compressive
    residual stress.
  \item The strengthening effect depends on the diameter of the part and the
    depth of the surface hardening.
\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're not stuck on the visual design, and just want some grouping, I'd try a `block`. No idea about doing this in LyX, but here's one in regular beamer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{madrid}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{block}{Surface Treatments}
\begin{columns}[c]
\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Carburizing
\item Nitriding
\item Flame hardening
\item Induction hardening
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Forming harder and stronger surface $\rightarrow$ introducing compressive residual stress
\item The strengthening effect depends on the diameter of the part and the depth of the surface hardening
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Something else}
This is just a placeholder. The slide may look better if this wasn't here.
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```